# Can someone explain the time complexity (Big-O) of this Java code and how to calculate it?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

```
public static int fun1(int[] arr, int index) {
  if (index <= 0) {
    return arr[0];
  }
  int m1 = fun1(arr, index - 1);
  int m2 = fun1(arr, index - 2);
  int m3 = fun1(arr, index - 4);
  if (m1 > m2) {
    return m1;
  } else if (m2 > m3) {
    return m3;
  } else {
    return m1;
  }
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken: `f(0) = c, f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-4) <= 3 * f(n-1) = 3 * f(n-1) = 3 * 3 * f(n-2) = 3 * 3 * 3 * f(n-3) = ... = 3^n * f(0) = 3^n * c ∈ O(3^n)`.

Comment: @user16320675 please if you see it again let me know

Comment: @Turing85 Mmm I think it's correct, but I want more details cause we solve it by equation something like that

Comment: That is literally the whole equation right there. There is nothing more to it. If you want to prove that `f(0) = c, f(n) = 3 * f(n-1)` is equal to `g(n) = 3^n * c` then this is off-topic for SO and would be more suitable on [math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/). But the proof should be straight-forward through induction.

Comment: @user16320675 Maybe I dunno

Answer (score 0):

One way is to observe: The 'point' of saying: "This algorithm is `O(n^2)`" is expressing the idea that if you run this algorithm for various values of `n` and you chart `n` (on the x-axis) against "runtime taken by this algorithm for an input with property 'n'" (on the y-axis), **eventually** (if you look far enough to the right), it looks just like the chart `y = x^2` looks. big-O notation gives you zero information about how far to the right you have to look, just that, as you look infinitely far, you *will* get to a slice that looks like that and will continue looking like that. It also just says "It looks like that", which is why constant factors are irrelevant.

You can try that - chart `y = x^2` and then chart `y = x^2 + x` and **eventually** the second chart looks identical to the first if you look far enough to the right. Make it `y = x^2 + 1000x` and this is still true; you just have to look way further right. That's why you'd never say something is `O(n^2 + n)` or even that something is `O(20n^2)` - because you're describing a shape of a chart and not an actual formula, and `20n^2` is not a different shape from just `n^2`.

So, you could actually model it with [JMH](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness) and make this chart. That's quite a bit of work, but a very enlightening exercise.

The answer is `O(3^n)`, and there are fairly easy ways to realize this. Your code on its own includes no loops of any kind, so a single invocation of this method (disregarding that it recurses) just counts as '1' (in big-O parlance, *other than* the recursion, your method's characteristic is `O(1)` - its runtime of the non-recursive part is not affected in any way by `n`). It does 1 to 3 comparisons between `m1` and `m3` regardless of the value of `n`, hence, constant factor, hence, irrelevant for big-O.

That just leaves the recursion, which is simply.. recursion. 3 times. There is no fancy trickery here: For an input of `n`, the first of your recursive calls is still linear to `n`, as are the second and third - subtracting 4 every time simply means it's linear to `n/4`, but constant factors don't matter, so they are *all* linear to `n`.

This boils down to 3^n. If you don't intuit that, use the fact you can eliminate constant factors and model it out:

For an input of '1', your method needs 1 go through (none of the recursers trigger at all), so `n=1, y = 1` (here 'y' is runtime).

For an input of '2', all 3 recurses trigger (they actually don't due to the -4, but we can disregard such constant trivialities when trying to figure out its big-O notation), but those recurses are then done, so that's 4 total. Continuing that math:

- x = 1, y1 = 1
- x = 2, y2 = 3*y1 + 1 = 4
- x = 3, y3 = 3*y2 + 1 = 13
- x = 4, y4 = 3*y3 + 1 = 40
- x = 5, y5 = 3*y4 + 1 = 121
- x = 6, y6 = 3*y5 + 1 = 364

and so on. 'previous, times 3' is 3^n. After all, breaking down e.g. the x=5 case, and again ditching constant factors:

`3*y4 = 3*3*y3 = 3*3*3*y2 = 3*3*3*3*y1`

and so on - it's 3*3.... `n` times: `3^n`.

Comment: In general, we were calculating the time complexity equation, so you think that the T(n-2) and T(n-4) have been rounded to become like T(n-1) so we got T(n)=3T(n-1)+c.

Am I got it right?

Comment: Yup, sounds right.